# How do I setup Datadog with Google App Engine node.js runtime?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, datadog

According to the [`gae_datadog` Github repo](https://github.com/DataDog/gae_datadog), the way to setup datadog in app engine is to clone the repo and add the following in `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
# Should probably be at the beginning of the list
# so it's not clobbered by a catchall route
- url: /datadog
  script: gae_datadog.datadog.app

env_variables:
    DATADOG_API_KEY: 'YOURAPIKEY'
```

However, this doesn't appear to work with their nodejs runtime. Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
# Copyright 2017, Google, Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START app_yaml]
handlers:
    # Should probably be at the beginning of the list
    # so it's not clobbered by a catchall route
    - url: /datadog
      script: gae_datadog.datadog.app

env_variables:
    DATADOG_API_KEY: 'MY_KEY'

runtime: nodejs
env: flex
# [END app_yaml]
```

It seems like the datadog url handler isn't used at all, because it 404. I assume the node.js app takes precedence here, but I don't know how to change that.

Comment: Hi did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: No, ended up not using it